# Setting up a SSH Lab using docker on my local machine

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, openssh

I am using docker ubuntu container to set up an SSH lab on my local machine. I have interactively started the container and installed open ssh on it with other tools. I ensured that I port forward container:22 to my localhost:2222

```
docker pull ubuntu
docker run -it --name ubunut-ssh-lab -p 2222:22 ubuntu /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y openssh-server
```

Then in sshd_config I have enabled PubKeyAuth to yes, have copied pub key from local machine to container directory .ssh/authroized_keys file. Restarted the service. I still get **root@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).**

I ran ssh connection using -v (verbose) arg.

```
ssh -v -i id_ubuntu_lab -p 2222 root@localhost
```

```
OpenSSH_9.3p2, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to localhost port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file id_ubuntu_lab type 0
debug1: identity file id_ubuntu_lab-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:2222 as 'root'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/sourabhdhingra/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:QanR0+0tbO3ombtQ17EvYU/yUoWTXJtBdZz7pPRHD7U
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/sourabhdhingra/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/sourabhdhingra/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /Users/sourabhdhingra/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 does not exist
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:2222 ([::1]:2222)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:QanR0+0tbO3ombtQ17EvYU/yUoWTXJtBdZz7pPRHD7U.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:2222' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: id_ubuntu_lab RSA SHA256:XghbmDcG+wgAFNV4/BdCxjwRtsnlBsmq9BiKmxEj5hU explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: id_ubuntu_lab RSA SHA256:XghbmDcG+wgAFNV4/BdCxjwRtsnlBsmq9BiKmxEj5hU explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I got above logs and error! I am attaching my sshd_config file here for analysis. Please check and help what is going wrong here.

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

Here is the output for `ls -la`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Oct 22 13:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4096 Oct 22 13:44 ..
-rw------- 1  501 dialout  602 Oct 22 13:54 authorized_keys
```

Note: I have only included uncommented lines from sshd_config.

What is the issue here? Not able to connect?

Comment: The logs from the SSH client connection do not have any useful error information.  You should post the logs from the SSH server to try and see why the publickey was denied.

Comment: What are the permissions and owners inside the container of ~root, ~root/.ssh, and ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys? If any of these are group writeable it might cause the sshd inside the container to ignore the authorized_keys file

Comment: Please run "ls -la" in root's .ssh directory, then [edit] your question to include the output.

Comment: @icarus 
here is the output
`
root@4e56fee1ea11:/# cd .ssh
root@4e56fee1ea11:/.ssh# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Oct 22 13:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4096 Oct 22 13:44 ..
-rw------- 1  501 dialout  602 Oct 22 13:54 authorized_keys
root@4e56fee1ea11:/.ssh# cd ..
root@4e56fee1ea11:/# ls -la .ssh
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Oct 22 13:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4096 Oct 22 13:44 ..
-rw------- 1  501 dialout  602 Oct 22 13:54 authorized_keys
`

Comment: @Kenster done! Please check

Comment: @GracefulRestart @icarus @Kenster 
Note that I am trying to do this with a docker container setup. This does not install many things to keep the image light.

`root@4e56fee1ea11:/etc# systemctl
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

I checked SyslogFacility AUTH it is commented out in sshd_config file but again I do not see auth.log in /var/log

Comment: @sourabhdhingra The "authorized_keys" file in root's .ssh directory has the wrong ownership. It should be owned by root.

Comment: @KensterI tried. still getting the below error ssh root@localhost -p 2222                                       ✔  08:22:59 
root@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).

Command used `chown root:root .ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Does the `ls -la ~/.ssh` now show the authorised_keys owned by root?

Comment: @icarus  yes actually there is no ~ in my case. I used docker ubuntu image here is the output
root@4e56fee1ea11:/# ls -la .ssh
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 22 13:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 22 13:44 ..
-rw------- 1 root root  602 Oct 22 13:54 authorized_keys

Comment: "There is no ~ in my case" - Are you sure? The files should in in `/root/.ssh`, not `/.ssh` unless you have edited the password file to change the home directory.

Comment: @icarus thanks for the pointers! I manually created root folder moved the .ssh folder, restarted the service and Voila! it worked! :) Thanks others too! Btw what was it that you mentioned "edited the password file to change the home directory"

Comment: The file /etc/passwd has a number of fields which include the home directory. Most modern systems have the home directory for the "root" set to "/root", but older ones have it set to "/". My point was that either you create the files in /root or you change the passwd file to set the home directory to "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a docker Ubuntu container, it is possible the image does not have the `/root` directory in it by default.

In this situation, trying `cd ~` in an interactive session with docker would give below:

```
root@4e56fee1ea11:/# cd ~
bash: cd: /root: No such file or directory
```

Therefore perform additional steps!

```
mkdir /root
mv .ssh /root
service ssh restart
```

And then login from your local machine

```
ssh -p 2222 root@localhost
```

Thanks for the contribution!